# Why we cannot use a geospatial index as a shard key in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

From [mongoDB document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-indexes-and-sharded-collections), sharding with geospatial index is not supported.

I don't understand why it cannot be supported because I think the geohash with the same length can be seen as regions without any overlap, so we can use them as shard keys.

[image]

Comment: My 2 cents: the ideal shard key should distribute data and query evenly in shards. To use geospatial index as the shard key might encounter some scenarios such as skewed data distribution (e.g. ZIPF value distribution) in real world.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Assuming in some way, the geospatial index could be evenly distributed, does this means that it can be used as shard keys?